Inconsistent Caching Behavior for MP3 Files in Safari Despite Proper Cache-Control Headers
I'm working on an Angular application that retrieves static data (JSON, MP3, and images) from a backend server, with a cache control response header set to Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000. I expect these files to be served from either disk or memory cache after the initial request. However, in Safari, the browser sometimes fetches the data from the cache and other times makes a network call. This inconsistent behavior is particularly noticeable with MP3 files, whereas JSON and image files are consistently served from the cache as expected.
I've tested this on multiple Safari versions and observed the same issue:

Version 17.2 (19617.1.17.11.9)
Version 17.1 (19616.2.9.11.7)
Version 17.3 (19617.2.4.11.8)

I confirmed that the "Disable Cache" option is not enabled in the developer tools, so the MP3 files should be cached. This functionality works correctly in Chrome and Firefox without any issues.
Is there any solution available to fix the issue?
